# How store user ID as session in login.php

Tags: php, authentication, user-accounts

I have the following functions in a file called user.php:

```
        function user_id_from_username($username) {
            $username = sanitize($username);
            return mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT `MemberID` FROM `member` WHERE `Email` = '$username'"),0, 'MemberID');

            }
        function login ($username, $password) {
            $MemberID = user_id_from_username ($username);

            $username = sanitize($username);
            $password = md5($password);

            return (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`MemberID`) FROM `member` WHERE `Email` = '$username' AND `Password` ='$password'"), 0) == 1) ? $MemberID : false; }
```

And in my login.php I have:

```
Session_start ();
include 'core/functions/users.php'

if (empty($_POST) === false){
    $username = $_POST['Email'];
    $password = $_POST['Password'];


        $login = login($username, $password);
        if($login === 1){
            $_SESSION['MemberID'] = $login; //logged in and returned user ID and store in session
            header('location: member.php?username='.$username);

        }else{
            // try admin login
            $query2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM admin WHERE Email ='$username' AND Password ='$password'");
            if(mysql_num_rows($query2) == 1){
                $_SESSION['Email'] = $username;
                header("location: admin.php");
            }
            else{
                 echo "Failed Login Attempt"; 

            }
        }
    }
```

When I try to log a user in I get this error:

Warning: mysql_result(): Unable to jump to row 0 on MySQL result index 8 in oddjobexchange\core\functions\user.php on line 27
Failed Login Attempt

I can't get my head around this error because I can't see anything wrong with line 27 (below)

```
return mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT `MemberID` FROM `member` WHERE `Email` = '$username'"),0, 'MemberID');
```

In my DB 'MemberID' is row 0, 'Email' is row 7 and 'Password' is row 8. Anybody know what I've got wrong?

Comment: Just a comment, you shouldn't be using `mysql_*` functions anymore.  Use msqli or PDO.

Comment: are you using `session_start()` on each page?

Comment: @Class yes I am, sorry forgot to copy it in.

Comment: is `Email` their username?

Comment: yeah their Email is $username, bit confusing I know.

Comment: what does `var_dump($_POST);` and `sanitize()` produce?

Comment: I got: Warning: mysql_result(): Unable to jump to row 0 on MySQL result index 8 in htdocs\oddjobexchange\core\functions\user.php on line 27
string(8) "MemberID" Failed Login Attempt